# Making fraction of hours with a comma seperator in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, time, sum, number-formatting, duration

Looking to make a fraction of an hour format with commas I've tried to format but couldn't figure out how, if anyone can help it would be appreciated

[image: the image]

Like Hour,FractionOfHour

New Image: [image: New Image that shows the spreadsheet]

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: ok will share now

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Nuo21xIXr31kkzTXN9zZ7tEpNEG-pqhse0gr7D8TwA4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

duration:

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/(SUM(F3:J4)/60/24)))
```

[image]

decimal:

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/(SUM(F3:J4)/60)))
```

[image]

### [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JwA6NRbb6lECO-mvE5EgLgeQQP_4u0iUdjxkixjQqWA/copy)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but here is the solution to display the time as a decimal

```
=HOUR(A1)+MINUTE(A1)/60+SECOND(A1)/3600
```

or

```
= TIMEVALUE(A1) * 24
```

where in cell **A1** is time

[image]

Comment: I will add a better image for you to understand thank you for giving me advice